Inverse-Fourier Recovery of Dirac Delta Coefficients
We have the Fourier transform $F: g\mapsto\hat{g}$ defined as follows:
$$\hat g(w) = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x)e^{-2\pi ixw} dx$$
and, using the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ and $c_j\in\mathbb{R}$, let
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c_j\delta(x-x_j).$$
Thus
$$\hat f(w)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c_je^{-2\pi ix_jw}.$$
How might one recover the $x_j$ and (distinct) $c_j$ values from $\hat f$?

What problem are you posing here?  If $\hat f$ specified for all $\omega$?

Yes; $\hat f$ is specified for all $w$ by the function above. My problem here is, given access to $\hat f$ as a blackbox function, how can one determine what the $c_j$ and $x_j$ constants are that define the original $f$, essentially recovering $f$ from $\hat f$.
